# .Net Core 3.1 Jwt Validate Issuer does not seem to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

Using .Net Core 3.1 WebApi with Jwt authentication seems to work fine unless we try to use ValidateIssuer and Validate Audience.
When we set these properties to true, we get an Unauthorized Http Status code.
We get the values for Audience and Issuer from our app settings, so we know they are the same.
Following is the code from our startup.cs:

```
//
// Configure JWT authentication from the 'jwtIssuerOptions' values in the appsettings.json file
//
Models.JwtIssuerOptions jwtSettings = _appConfiguration.GetSection("jwtIssuerOptions").Get<Models.JwtIssuerOptions>();
var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.JwtSecret);
SymmetricSecurityKey symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes);

services.AddAuthentication(a =>
{
    a.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    a.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(b =>
    {
        b.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        b.SaveToken = true;
        b.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience =  jwtSettings.Audience ,
            ValidIssuer =  jwtSettings.Issuer ,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey,
            TokenDecryptionKey = symmetricSecurityKey,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true
        };
    });
```

Following is the code from our Auth Helper that creates the Jwt:

```
private void CreateTheJWT(EndUserCredentials user)
{            
    var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwtIssuerOptions.JwtSecret);
    var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes);
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
    var cryptoKey = new EncryptingCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, JwtConstants.DirectKeyUseAlg, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512);
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Name),
            new Claim("EndUser", System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize( user)),
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_jwtIssuerOptions.TimeoutMinutes),
        Audience = _jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer,
        Issuer = _jwtIssuerOptions.Audience,
        NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-2),
        IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1),
        SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
        EncryptingCredentials = cryptoKey
    };

    foreach (string role in user.Roles)
    {
        tokenDescriptor.Subject.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

When we set the offending properties to "false", everything works.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems to me that your issuer and audiance are swapped. can you reassign in CreateTheJWT function?

```
Audience = _jwtIssuerOptions.Audience,
Issuer = _jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are here like me and you didn't swap your issuer and audience.

Ensure you have this in your Startup.ConfigureServices.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```